# How to check for all empty edit text dynamically and show corresponding message in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Some times we have a lot of edit text input field and we have to check all input fields and need to show specific message according to input type which is too much irritating to check all one by one and show message.So is there any way to check all the  input field dynamically and show messages just by one method ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is too much irriating while there is a lot of input fields.Once i have to check 25 input fields for empty and needed to show specific message and this time i   have created a way to check all input fields and show messages dynamically by using just one method.I'm sharing my way.
in editText there is an option to set tag to each edittext.So i just set tag to each edittext after type casting of them.like-

```
 etEmail.setTag("email");
 if(emptyChecker(new EditText[]{etEmail})){
// do your task
}
```

and after that on submit button i just called my created method with an array of edittext. The method is below-

```
/**
 * input field empty checker
 *
 * @param editTexts
 * @return
 */

public static boolean emptyChecker(EditText[] editTexts, Activity activity) {
    /**
     * checking input field for empty or not
     */
    int totalLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++) {
        EditText editText = editTexts[i];
        if (editText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, editTexts[i].getTag().toString().toLowerCase() + " " + activity.getString(R.string.is_empty), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        } else {
            if (editText.getTag().toString().toLowerCase().equals(activity.getString(R.string.email).toLowerCase())) {
                String email = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                if (!email.matches(emailPattern)) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.invalid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                } else {
                    totalLength++;
                }
            } else {
                totalLength++;
            }

        }
    }
    //true means all okay
    //false means at least one is empty
    return totalLength == editTexts.length;
}
```

here i took one array of edittext and after i looped through the array.On each edittext i checked if this is empty or not.if empty then i took the tag of that edittext and append with ** is empty** and showed on a toast.And then if the edittext is not empty then i checked the tag with **email**.So if it email then i used regex to validate the email and if it is valid then i increment  the counter and if not then i break the the loop and showed an toast.And if it is not email type then i just increment the counter.And finally i have returned the boolean value by comparing the counter length with the edittext array length as there's counter is incremented only when the edittext is not empty.So the idea is if all edit texts are not empty then the counter size will be same as edittext array's length.And if any edit text is empty or email is not matches with the regex then i have shown message by getting the tag of edittext and concat with **is empty**. This will show the message dynamically.
You just need to settag to the edittext and pass it as array to this method and do your task if the return value is true and the all other task will be done in this simple method.